# pybind11 wrapper build with custom so file

Tags: python, c, pybind11

I'm writing wrapper for c/cpp source code. I am building pybind11 wrapper with CMake. I have linked my existing (libcore.so)so file with wrapper,

verified that my core.so is linked with pywrapper module

```
$ldd pywrapper.cpython-37m-aarch64-linux-gnu.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x0000ffffbe51a000)
        libcore.so => soundar-workspace/pybind11/libcore.so (0x0000ffffbe3d6000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x0000ffffbe1ea000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x0000ffffbe140000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x0000ffffbe11b000)
```

CMake command used for linking so file:

pybind11_add_module(pywrapper wrapper.cpp)

target_link_libraries(pywrapper PRIVATE core)

**header.h**

```
typedef enum {
    E_FLAG_ON = 0,
    E_FLAG_OFF
} option;

typedef struct {
    float *a;
    float b;
    char *file_path; 
    option flag;
} inputs;

// API
int op_init(const inputs*);
```

I have written wrapper only for structure and enum in header and not for the API's, since i have linked the so file

**wrapper.cpp**

```
py::class_<inputs>(m, "inputs")
    .def(py::init<>())
    .def_readwrite("a", &inputs::a) 
    .def_readwrite("b", &inputs::b)
    .def_readwrite("file_path", &inputs::file_path)
    .def_readwrite("flag", <>) 

#Not added m.def() for API's in header, but i have directly linked the so file having the 'op_init' API. But i couldn't access the API's
```

Error output: i am getting,

```
$ python3 test_app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_app.py", line 6, in <module>
    pywrapper.op_init(obj)
AttributeError: module 'pywrapper' has no attribute 'op_init'
```

Question:

1. Do i need the build entire source code along with wrapper.cpp instead of linking directly the so file?
2. If so, do i need to add m.def() for the APIs i want to use in wrapper module?

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide bindings for every function and class you want to be able to use from Python. In other words, if you want to use `op_init` from Python you need to have something like this in your `wrapper.cpp`:

```cpp
[...]
m.def("op_init", &MyAPI::op_init);
```

Comment: @Ir1985, how to define arguments for the APIs? 
'op_init' -> has 1 mandatory NULL structure pointer input | 
'callback' -> is a callback API has 3 optional arguments.

Comment: You'll have to follow the pybind docs for that. In general you don't need to define the arguments, pybind's magic will do that automatically. However, the argument types have to also be exported to python to make the whole thing work.

Comment: yeah variable arguments we can define using py::arg() but some in my case i want to register callback function as argument to one api. for that i didn't get any reference in docs

Comment: You can easily do that by using `std::function` and/or lambda functions, but you'll have to either add that to the question or make a new question if you want a specific answer.

Comment: yes already raised separate question to get a clear and specific answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72937616/defining-arguments-and-callbacks-functions-for-apis-in-pybind11-wrapper)